# Autoload PHP não está funciononando

Tags: php

Eu estou usando o composer para gerar meu autoload. O composer.json está assim:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "Classes\\":"Classes/",
            "Interfaces\\":"Interfaces/"
        }
    }
}
```

independente se eu tenho carregar uma interface ou uma classe da o mesmo erro. Tenho 4 pastas irmãs (Classes, Interfaces, Dao e Vendor).

O erro do index.php (que está fora das 3 pastas) é o seguinte:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Classes\Pedido\Pedido' not found
>   in C:\laragon\www\comanda_eletronica\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\comanda_eletronica\index.php on line 4

meu index.php está assim:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'\vendor\autoload.php';

$p = new \Classes\Pedido\Pedido;
```

A minha Classe pedido está assim:

```
<?php

namespace Classes\Pedido;


class Pedido {}
```

lembrando que a classe Pedido está dentro da pasta Classes. Já tentei muita coisa que encontrei na net, mas nada me ajudou, apenas se eu ignorar o autoload e fazer um include dos arquivos que eu preciso.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVIDO] Eu apenas mudei meu composer.json para:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Classes\\": "Classes\\",
            "Interfaces\\": "Interfaces\\"}
    }
}
```

e todos os namespaces das classes eu mudei para apenas "Classes"